# Pass variable to Binance API not working for client.get_asset_balance()

Tags: python, binance

I'm retrieving two asset balances. I've set my code so that I only need to enter my pair once.

```
crypto = 'BTC' #coin
base = 'USDT'  # stable-coin
symbol = crypto+base
```

I then try to pass these variables to certain functions, but I'm getting an error for one.
This one works just as it should, and returns data:

`base_Bal_p = client.get_asset_balance(asset=base, timestamp=timestamp, recvWindow=recvWindow)`

This one gives an error:

`crypto_Bal_p = client.get_asset_balance(asset=crypto, timestamp=timestamp, recvWindow=recvWindow)`

Error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lower'

It will work if I code it like this:

`crypto_Bal_p = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC', timestamp=timestamp, recvWindow=recvWindow)`

Any ideas?

I honestly don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like get_asset_balance should return a string, but is returning a dataframe type instead.

Comment: I guess if you have multiple assets it would have to be a dataframe, but it gets weird because "base"  works fine, even though there are multiple.